# PySpark with AWS: Unable to use external process for credentials in PySpark, but they work with AWS CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

Apologies in advance for any poor formatting, I've never posted a question before!

I am trying to configure Glue local execution via a Docker container for dev and testing purposes. In our setup, to connect locally to AWS we use an external process provider in the config file (~/.aws/config), this is a custom Python script that we have written and has been working for us for some time for using the AWS CLI and also the AWS Toolkit extension for VS Code - so the AWS SDKs should be able to pick this up.

The structure of the config file is as follows - edited to obscure details

```
[profile default]
credential_process = /root/cloud_workflow/creds_process.sh param1 param2 param3
region=eu-west-1
```

creds_process.sh contains:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source /opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate glue_env && python /root/path/dev_credential_update.py "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

I've double checked and the aws cli commands work as expected within the Docker container itself - e.g. I've tried aws s3 ls and had no issue executing this.

Now when running the Glue code via a Jupyter notebook which is connected to the kernel within the Docker container I've hit the following exception - again edited to obscure details

```
23/07/07 11:37:56 WARN MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
23/07/07 11:37:57 WARN CredentialsLegacyConfigLocationProvider: Found the legacy config profiles file at [/root/.aws/config]. Please move it to the latest default location [~/.aws/credentials].
23/07/07 11:37:58 WARN FileStreamSink: Assume no metadata directory. Error while looking for metadata directory in the path: s3://OBSCURED_S3_PATH/file.dat.
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3://OBSCURED_S3_PATH/file.dat: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: You must specify a value for roleArn and roleSessionName, com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@30b4d41d: Failed to refresh process-based credentials., com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@6d4e133d: Forbidden (Service: null; Status Code: 403; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:212)
```

I believe the most relevant part is

```
com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@30b4d41d: Failed to refresh process-based credentials
```

We are pulling the following spark and maven versions into our Docker container from these sources:
MAVEN=https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/glue-common/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz
SPARK=https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/glue-4.0/spark-3.3.0-amzn-1-bin-3.3.3-amzn-0.tgz

Finally the code which has generated this exception - edited to be the minimum code for the issue to present and obscured

```python
import findspark
findspark.init()

## import packages
import sys
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import boto3
import pandas as pd

sc = SparkContext()
#sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider")
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

partitions="s3://OBSCURED_S3_PATH/file.dat"
partition_list = partitions.split(",")

columns_to_select = ["column_a", "column_b", "column_c", "column_d", "column_e", "column_f", "column_g", "column_h", "column_partition"]
df_lvt = spark.read.parquet(*partition_list, additional_options = {"useS3ListImplementation":True}).select(columns_to_select)
```

The final line of code is where the exception is triggered. Any advice on getting PySpark to work with the credential_process method would be appreciated as ideally we'd like to keep only to this approach.

I've checked that none of the AWS related environment variables are set, and have also tried manually setting AWS_PROFILE and AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE to no change in behaviour.

I've confirmed that using the credentials manually via the credentials file (both credentials and config) does work as expected but this approach would make our developer flow much more frustrating to use as we'd need to manually refresh these every 60 minutes.

Comment: the s3a connector has an option to take a list of aws credential providers, which can include those in the AWS SDK. One of those in the sdk does (somehow) execute a process and get the answer -but i don't know how you'd configure it. You may have to implement in java/spark a new AwsCredentialsProvider which calls the code. this could be something you could even contribute back to open source

Comment: @stevel thanks for your comment! Unfortunately at the minute time constraints wouldn't allow me to implement this but nice to know I wasn't missing anything really obvious. For the curious, in the meantime I've implemented a solution where I have a cron job running every 30 minutes within the docker container which calls a variant of my existing script and outputs the credentials directly into the credential file - not quite as elegant but still gets the job done!

Comment: workarounds are always the best way to get something shipping., so good to know you are happy